# jQuery UI Droppable Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, drag-and-drop, coffeescript

Having a hard time debugging this one.

Using jQuery UI Droppable in a Backbone application using CoffeeScript.

There is nothing wrong with the functionality, everything is working how I intended it to, but I am still getting this console error every time an item is dropped.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
```

Code for the droppable:

```
@$el.droppable
        tolerance: 'pointer'
        hoverClass: 'drop_hover'
        accept: '.item'

        drop: (e, ui) =>
            draggedItem = ui.draggable

            itemId = draggedItem.attr 'data-id'

            allInstances = @model.collection.models

            findItems = for instance in allInstances
                          instanceItems = instance.get 'items'
                          instanceItems.getByCid itemId


            compacted = _.compact findItems

            droppedItem = compacted[0]

            droppedCollection = droppedItem.collection

            droppedCollection.remove droppedItem if _.include droppedCollection.models, droppedItem

            @itemCollection.add droppedItem unless _.include @items, droppedItem
```

Like I said the functionality is working properly, I just would like to get rid of the error if someone knows anything I could try to debug.

Stack Trace

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
a.ui.plugin.add.stopjquery-ui.js:49
a.ui.version.a.extend.plugin.call       jquery-ui.js:9
a.widget._trigger                       jquery-ui.js:49
a.widget._mouseStop                     jquery-ui.js:49
a.widget._mouseUp                       jquery-ui.js:28
a.widget._mouseUp                       jquery-ui.js:49
a.widget._mouseDown._mouseUpDelegate    jquery-ui.js:28
f.event.dispatch                        jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i                  jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is the stack trace of the error giving you any hint?

Comment: Nothing useful to me. I added it to the question.

Comment: Looks like a jQuery issue then. Take a look at this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/on-draggable-destroy-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-options-of-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be finally fixed properly in v1.11.0, without all of the workarounds proposed here:

> http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6889

It seems that removing the original draggable item now will not result in this error because properties are now stored on the `instance` field. I've confirmed that v1.11.0 fixes this exact error that popped up on v1.10.4.

Answer (score 8):

It does appear to be related to destroying the dropped item during the drop event. I was able to get around the issue by delaying the destroy call:

```
function(evt,ui) {
    setTimeout((function() {
        $(this).draggable("destroy");
    }).bind(ui.draggable),50);
}
```

Comment: Where should I have to write this? I getting same error to whom you answered. I up voted your answer as it seems to resolution to my question too.

Answer (score 5):

For me, none of the proposed solutions worked. As you already mentioned, this is because of the removal of the element before the drop finishes. My very easy solution to this was not to `remove()` the element, but to only `detach()` the element and append it somewhere else.

So for me I moved from:

```
aDiv.droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    ui.draggable.remove();
    anotherDiv.append(ui.draggable);
  }
})
```

which gave me the options exception to:

```
aDiv.droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    ui.draggable.detach();
    anotherDiv.append(ui.draggable);
  }
})
```

As the [jQuery's detach() documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) this works because it "...keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements."

If detach and append is an option for you, it appears to me to be a very clean solution.

Comment: Thanks man, helped me. In case of repeating(1000 times) detach(), will this cause to memory leak?

Comment: Detach only "unlinks" the element from the DOM, so its not creating new objects. The memory footprint should stay roughly the same. Though, if you really don't need the elements anymore I would definitely completely remove them later. Maybe a `setTimeout(..., 1000)` that actually removes them after a delay, works for you.

Comment: I've heard that `setTimeOut(...,0)` causes the function act somehow asynchronously, can I use it here or I have to use a certain amount of time (like what you said)?

Comment: I would not go with 0 ms but a much higher value. You'll have to figure out which one is still acceptable for your application and trigger it on drop.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same error, and I think, from my testing that it happens when you detach or remove the dropped item on the drop event.
when using the original element as the helper.

I'm still looking for a better way to detach and re-insert the dragged element into the DOM

Answer (score 1):

@dira pointed to a thread with a problem surrounding the same code in jQuery UI, but the solution there didn't work for me.

I ended up commenting out the code in the jQuery UI source and the error went away.

As before, everything still works as desired.

The block I commented out:

```
$.ui.plugin.add("draggable", "cursor", {
  start: function(event, ui) {
    var t = $('body'), o = $(this).data('draggable').options;
    if (t.css("cursor")) o._cursor = t.css("cursor");
    t.css("cursor", o.cursor);
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    var o = $(this).data('draggable').options;
    if (o._cursor) $('body').css("cursor", o._cursor);
  }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

My approach to resolve this is to make use of the STOP event of draggable.

When an item is dropped and ready to remove, fire an event back to the draggable view to set @isRemove = true. The draggable view should have something like this in the STOP event:

```
self = @
@$(".selector").draggable
  stop: (event, ui) ->
    if self.isRemove
      self.remove()
```